# Not able to record a simple login page test with Jmeter for a Tomcat 6 running on localhost but can for Jmeter Website

Tags: firefox, tomcat, browser, proxy, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and had a look at the apache user manual as well but not able to resolve my problem, which is not able to record my test. Basically i have a simple login app running on apache tomcat 6(HTTP port 8082). I have created a thread group and and added an HTTP Default Request to it please find config below:

[image]

I have also created a Proxy Server please find config below:

[image: Proxy Server Config]

I have also updated the proxy for my firefox please find below:

[image]

My login application is running on the Apache Tomcatv6.0 as i can view it on the browser. However with the above setting i am not able to record anything don't know what i am doing wrong?when i change the server name/ip to http://jmeter.apache.org/ then it works find. Any idea why it is not recording when i am running my application please?My login application displays an html login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in your firefox settings you have set in No proxy for:

- localhost

As below:
[image]

So to fix it, just remove from "No proxy for" the localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: @UBIK LOAD PACK I have the same problem but I don't understand your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a port number other than `:8080`. For example you can use `:2020`